# Django Heroku stops collecting static assets

Tags: python, django, heroku

I have run into this problem 2x where heroku just stops running collectstatic. The dry run works fine. Even running the command "appears" to copy the files over but does not actually do anything.  The only solution I have come up with is to manually collect the static files locally and check them into the branch I am pushing to heroku.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15856358/heroku-collectstatic-not-run-during-deployment

Answer (score 0):

Try to install gunicorn, put it in your requirements and use following Procfile:

```
web: python manage.py collectstatic --dry-run --noinput; python manage.py run_gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:$PORT
```

It will automatically collect the static assets and don't forget to set-up STATIC_ROOT & STATIC_URL.

Comment: I already use gunicorn and the addition of the collectstatic command doesn't seem to actually collect the assets to the appropriate directory.