# collectstatic command not run when deploying to Heroku, but setup is perfectly fine

Tags: django, heroku, collectstatic

Things I have verified:

- my `collectstatic` directory (yes, I call it like that, to reduce confussion with `static` source directories) is in my repo (via a `.gitkeep` file) (as advised in the [heroku documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets))
- `heroku run python manage.py collectstatic --dry-run --noinput` works (suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15858757/647991))
- collectstatic is **not** forcefully disabled: `heroku config:add DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=0`
- I am pushing a new commit (so heroku is actually deploying)

Still, `collectstatic` is not run. What more could I check?

### EDIT

Also, I properly define `STATIC_ROOT` in `settings.py`. Relevant section below:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'collectstatic/')

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
```

### EDIT2

My installed apps are just stock django 1.9:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

### EDIT3

One thing I must mention, which is maybe relevant: `DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC` was set to 1 previously (so forcefully disabled) for this one heroku app, but I have made sure it is now set to 0.

Maybe a bug in Heroku prevents it from using the latest value? I guess the only way to check this is to create a new heroku app.

Comment: Did you add the `collectstatic` directory to your STATIC_DIRS in your settings.py?

Comment: @Remi: sure, question editted. Actually not to `STATICFILES_DIRS` (that's what you mean, right?) but to `STATIC_ROOT`: `collectstatic` is the output directory. The source static directories are defined in `STATICFILES_DIRS` and I just call them `static`

Comment: Have you tried adding the directory specifically like this: STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'collectstatic'),
)

Comment: No, and I don't want to since that does not make sense. `collecstatic` is not a source directory, and should not be searched when collecting static files (which is the meaning of `STATICFILES_DIRS`)

Comment: ah ok, understood. And you only have one settings file that you are using?

Comment: Yes, only one `settings.py` (and currently a single `static` entry in `STATICFILES_DIRS`, but that is not relevant)

Comment: And is staticfiles included in INSTALLED_APPS in that settings file?

Comment: @DanielRoseman: yep! Question editted

Comment: have you tried without the dry-run flag?

Comment: @Remi: yes, and when called manually it works, but that is not good for production, since that creates collectstatic in the context of the one-off dyno, which is not what I need. That **is exactly** what `heroku push` should trigger, but is not.

Answer (score 0):

So, no idea what is going on, but creating a new Heroku instance and pushing to it with an empty configuration is actually triggering collectstatic.

I suspect Heroku is not properly evaluating changes to `DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC`.

### EDIT

Actually, it seems `DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=0` **also** prevents `collectstatic` to run. To make sure collectstatic runs, do:

```
heroku config:unset DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC
```

I would say the [Heroku documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets#disabling-collectstatic) is a bit confusing, since it seems to imply that `DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=0` will in fact run collectstatic - but it doesn't.